# Transport pass for one week in Mallorca

Tags: public-transport, spain, transportation, mallorca

I will be in **Mallorca** for one week. Is there transport card, weekly pass or something like this?

I've been last year in Malta and I bought one card and was able to travel with their public transport everywhere on the island.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any such scheme for Mallorca.

Public transport in Mallorca can generally fit into 3 categories - EMT buses which are local services around Palma, CTM buses which are longer distances buses across the island and rail services.

CTM don't seem to list any form of unlimited travel passes on their website (https://www.tib.org/en/web/ctm/bitllets-i-abonaments) - you can pre-purchae blocks of tickets in groups of 20 or 40 - these look to be designed for people traveling the same route so may not be suitable. You'll also need an intermodal card to purchase these tickets which you'll need to obtain on the Island - they are not posted off it - from one of these places: https://www.tib.org/web/ctm/targeta-intermodal/modalitats - note that only a small number can issue the passes instantly, you'll also need to take ID. I can't fine anything about this on the CTM website, but others do report that the pass is only issued to local residents: https://www.seemallorca.com/buses

EMT also don't have a clear solution on there page (http://www.emtpalma.cat/en/fares), they do offer an unlimited pass but the minimum period is 30 days and you'll need a citizens card - which requires you be a local resident. EMT do pre-sell blocks of 10 tickets at a discount, but these cannot be bought on the bus, only from seperate approved outlets, list: http://www.emtpalma.cat/en/10-trips-card